# Partitioning by multiple columns in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

With Spark SQL's window functions, I need to partition by multiple columns to run my data queries, as follows:

`val w = Window.partitionBy($"a").partitionBy($"b").rangeBetween(-100, 0)`

I currently do not have a test environment (working on settings this up), but as a quick question, is this currently supported as a part of Spark SQL's window functions, or will this not work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This won't work. The second `partitionBy` will overwrite the first one. Both partition columns have to be specified in the same call:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"a", $"b").rangeBetween(-100, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the columns at multiple places where you are doing partitionBy then you could assign that to a variable in form of list and then use that list directly as a argument value for the partitionBy in the code.

```
val partitioncolumns = List("a","b")
val w = Window.partitionBy(partitioncolumns:_*).rangeBetween(-100, 0)
```

By using `:_*` at the end of the list variable it convert that to varargs and that is the argument type that partitionBy takes. So your code would work the way you want.