# Partitioning by multiple columns in PySpark with columns in a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

My question is similar to this thread:
[Partitioning by multiple columns in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795488/partitioning-by-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql#)

but I'm working in Pyspark rather than Scala and I want to pass in my list of columns as a list. I want to do something like this:

```python
column_list = ["col1","col2"]
win_spec = Window.partitionBy(column_list)
```

I can get the following to work:

```python
win_spec = Window.partitionBy(col("col1"))
```

This also works:

```python
col_name = "col1"
win_spec = Window.partitionBy(col(col_name))
```

And this also works:

```python
win_spec = Window.partitionBy([col("col1"), col("col2")])
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Convert column names to column expressions with a list comprehension `[col(x) for x in column_list]`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import Window
column_list = ["col1","col2"]
win_spec = Window.partitionBy([col(x) for x in column_list])
```

Comment: Update for people coming to this answer: Newer versions of pyspark allow you to pass in a list, like the answers below. See @Naguveeru's answer.

Answer (score 8):

PySpark >= 2.4, this works too =>

```
column_list = ["col1","col2"]

win_spec = Window.partitionBy(*column_list)
```

Comment: Just a quick question, the ```*``` stands for all items in ```column_list``` , did I understand the code correctly?

Comment: @Vanessa_C quite late, but the `*` operator is used to unpack an iterable into a function call in Python. Instead of passing `"col1", "col2"` (manually) to the function call, by using `*column_list` you are also doing exactly that, but without having to specify each element in the list.

Answer (score 6):

Your first attempt should work.

Consider the following example:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("a", "apple", 1),
        ("a", "orange", 2),
        ("a", "orange", 3),
        ("b", "orange", 3),
        ("b", "orange", 5)
    ],
    ["name", "fruit","value"]
)
df.show()
#+----+------+-----+
#|name| fruit|value|
#+----+------+-----+
#|   a| apple|    1|
#|   a|orange|    2|
#|   a|orange|    3|
#|   b|orange|    3|
#|   b|orange|    5|
#+----+------+-----+
```

Suppose you wanted to calculate a fraction of the sum for each row, grouping by the first two columns:

```python
cols = ["name", "fruit"]
w = Window.partitionBy(cols)
df.select(cols + [(f.col('value') / f.sum('value').over(w)).alias('fraction')]).show()

#+----+------+--------+
#|name| fruit|fraction|
#+----+------+--------+
#|   a| apple|     1.0|
#|   b|orange|   0.375|
#|   b|orange|   0.625|
#|   a|orange|     0.6|
#|   a|orange|     0.4|
#+----+------+--------+
```