# Why is mypy in pyspark confused between Sequence[str] and Union[str,List[str]?

Tags: python, pyspark, mypy, python-typing

I have a function that creates a pyspark WindowSpec partitioning on either a single column or a pair of columns in a list, depending on a boolean param. Mypy throws an error that I can't understand, because my parameter `partition_cols` should be `Union[str, List[str]]` which is acceptable for `Window.partitionBy()`.

Example method and error:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window, WindowSpec


def get_window(single_column: bool) -> WindowSpec:

    partition_cols = "key" if single_column else ["key", "name"]

    return Window.partitionBy(partition_cols).orderBy("timestamp").rangeBetween(0, 10)
```

Then running mypy:

```
$ mypy tmp.py
tmp.py:8: error: Argument 1 to "partitionBy" of "Window" has incompatible type "Sequence[str]"; expected "Union[Union[Column, str], List[Union[Column, str]]]"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: Wow, it's a really bad design decision in pyspark. First, `list` is invariant, so even `list[str]` is not allowed for this function, so only unpacking is a valid option. It also checks for `isinstance(..., list)`, so you cannot pass a `tuple` and other sequences (at least), and maybe even `set` should be supported here. This is awkward: either deny this scenario (allow only `*str`) or support it properly, `list` is not the only sequence in python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar happened to this user and thread: [Partitioning by multiple columns in PySpark with columns in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49241264/partitioning-by-multiple-columns-in-pyspark-with-columns-in-a-list)

Found that this solution was working for me :)

```
column_list = ["col1","col2"]

win_spec = Window.partitionBy(*column_list)
```